# Query doesn't add parameters' value when executed

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, parameters, sql-injection

I want to insert multiple rows into my database, I tried to use parameters but I did something wrong.

In debug mode, the parameters do have values, but once the insert is done, I still have `@compte`, `@mo`, `@userimp` in my database instead of their values.

```
string INSERTDELAMORTPart2 = "'123'," + "'@compte'" + "," + "'@mo'" + "," + "'ubs'" + "," + "'2'" + "," + "'@userimp'" + "," + "'22.10.17'" + ",'";

OdbcCommand Query = new OdbcCommand(INSERTDELAMORTPart2, InfoConnexion); 

Query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@compte", _cb_Compte.SelectedItem);
Query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mo", MondantResultat);
Query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userimp", UserImp);

Query.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I have tried `Parameters.Add`, and also `Parameters["@name"].Value`, but the result stays the same.

What am I doing wrong ?

**EDIT :**

I have an Oracle database and I need the single quote to insert my values.
I have tried to pass my whole INSERT string into a parameter but it doesn't work.

I'm about to give up and just replace the `'` by `''` even if it's a bad idea.

Comment: Don't use string concatenation, use parameters for everything.

Comment: Query in the post does not use parameters but simply quoted strings... Are you sure you pasted correct sample?

Comment: Additionally, you've specified single quotes around your parameters, which means you'll try to insert the parameter *names* as strings, not their values.

Comment: I have change my string to INSERTDELAMORTPart2 = "'123'," + "@compte" + "," + "@mo" + "," + "'ubs'" + "," + "'2'" + "," + "@userimp" + "," + "'22.10.17'" + ",'"; But if i delete the double-quote i get the error compte, mo and userimp don't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things.

1. If you are using Oracle, I highly recommend you use ODP.net or managed ODP.net, not ODBC.  ODBC *should* work, but the native drivers will work more efficiently and will avoid any oddities you might with with the abstraction layer ODBC provides.  Managed ODP.net has the additional advantage of not requiring an Oracle client be installed on the target machine
2. SQL Server (and other databases) use the "@" as a parameter, but Oracle uses the colon ":" instead.  Some databases (like PostgreSQL) will take either.  While the parameter in your SQL requires the colon, when you use assign the parameter in .NET you need to omit it.  Again, this is an Oracle thing you won't find in other databases.
3. Your SQL doesn't appear to have any command in it... only values.  Where is your "insert into?"
4. Especially with Oracle, you want to be explicit about your datatypes...  so use `Add` instead of `AddWithValue` (which is actually an overload of `Add` in ODP.net).  Alternatively, you can set the datatype later.

The converted code would look something like this:

```
string insert = "insert into my_table values (:COMPTE, :MO, :USERIMP)";

using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(insert, Connection))
{
    // no ":" in the parameter declarations
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("COMPTE", OracleDbType.Int32));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("MO", OracleDbType.Varchar2));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("USERIMP", OracleDbType.Varchar2));
    cmd.Parameters[0].Value = 123;
    cmd.Parameters[1].Value = "ubs";
    cmd.Parameters[2].Value = "22.10.17";

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

I guessed at your datatypes -- make sure they match your DDL when you actually implement this, and if these aren't the only three columns, update your insert command appropriately.

If for some reason I misunderstood, and this is not Oracle, I still recommend use of the native driver rather than ODBC.  When you use ODBC, you assume a lot about the target machine -- assumptions that may not turn out to be true.

Comment: I changed my "@" by ":" and used the `.Add` then `.Value` and it worked.

I spent  my whole weekend for this.  BIG THANK YOU.

PS: The use of the ODBC driver is in the specification.

Comment: I'm so glad.  I added the Oracle tag to your question, just in case anyone else ever runs into a similar issue.  Thanks for letting me know it worked.  If you ever have to do thousands of inserts, do check out ODP.net.  It has bulk insert/update that will make it worth it.

Answer (score 2):

The command should look something like this:

```
insert into t(compte, mo, userimp) -- of course the table and columns should be the right names
    values (@compte, @mo, @userimp);
```

No single quotes are needed.

I would recommend against using `AddWithValue()`.  Instead, be explicit about the types.

Comment: I can't delete the double-quote or I get the error that compte, mo and userimp don't exist

Comment: @FistiPaul . . . This answer says nothing about double quotes.  It refers to single quotes in the query.

Answer (score 1):

You have this:

```
string INSERTDELAMORTPart2 = "'123'," + "'@compte'" ...
```

Note the single quotes around the parameter names. They should not be there. You want this instead:

```
string INSERTDELAMORTPart2 = "'123'," + "@compte"
```

Comment: If I delete the single quotes, I get a missing expression when I insert. Even if I try to insert by myself in SQL without the single quotes I get an invalid column error.

PS:`@compte` has a value of "CH1800767000Z52461335"

Is there a way to load the value into `@compte` before `.ExecuteNonQuery()` ? So I can add to my string those single quotes that I need.